# Can't get the GRUB menu when starting my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: grub2, password

I am a novice willing to learn !

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from a USB key on my Acer Aspire e1 571G since June 2020 as unique system running my computer. It was formerly ran by Windows.

I changed my password some days ago, forgot it, and I now wish to change it.

I've read the advice on forums which match with my case, However, I can't access the GRUB system. All I get when I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is : "Minimal bash-like editing is supported ..." with a terminal `grub> _` where I'm allowed to write.

Actually, I don't know by which miracle I manage to start my machine without password. I think I kind of "tired" it by pressing too much the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as I was following the instructions about connecting to the GRUB.

I wish a sustainable solution => change my forgotten password to then erase it ! (no more password)

Could somebody help me?

Comment: I believe the `grub>` -prompt appears on hitting `ESC` twice... So: retry, make sure to 'tap' the key, a very short single hit.